# Make request.post execute in sequence

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a `E2E` test written in `Protractor-Jasmine` for my `Angular2-TypeScript` Application as below,

```
it("Perform Some Action", function() {

    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Email"]')).sendKeys(test_email);
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Password"]')).sendKeys("pass");
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Confirm Password"]')).sendKeys("conf pass");
    element(by.buttonText("CONTINUE")).click();

    request.post(
      'myAPIEndPoint',
      { json: { emailaddress: test_email,user: "user1",code: "1234" } },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body)
          var info = JSON.parse(body);
          //Do something
        }
      }
    );
```

Now, the problem I am facing is that, the `request.post` is getting called before the statements above it and causing my tests to fail as the response from api post call will have value only if the statements above it will be executed before post call.

What is the proper way to ensure that the `post-call` is done only after the statements above it are executed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because most of protractor instructions are done asynchronously. The same applies to `sendKeys()` and `click()`.

You need to do two things:

1. Perform request when `click()` promise is resolved (in the `.then()` method)
2. Inform your Jasmine that the asynchronous job is done, and it can go on with rest of suite (using `it('description', function(done){})` structure

Your TC would look like below:

```
it("Perform Some Action", function(done) {
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Email"]')).sendKeys(test_email);
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Password"]')).sendKeys("pass");
    element(by.css('[ng-reflect-placeholder="Confirm Password"]')).sendKeys("conf pass");
    element(by.buttonText("CONTINUE")).click().then(()=> {
        request.post(
          'myAPIEndPoint',
          { json: { emailaddress: test_email,user: "user1",code: "1234" } },
          function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              console.log(body)
              var info = JSON.parse(body);
              //Do something
              done();
            }
          }
        );
    });
});
```